# ScrollViewReader not scrolling to the correct id with anchor

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollviewreader

### Problem

- First time when the button "Go to 990" is tapped the scroll view doesn't scroll to 990 on **top**. (see screenshot below)
- The anchor is not respected.
- Second time it scrolls to 990 top correctly.

### Questions

1. What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

### Versions

- Xcode 14

### Code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scrollProxy: ScrollViewProxy?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                List(0..<1000, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("cell \(index)")
                            .font(.title)
                        Text("text 1")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                        Text("text 2")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    scrollProxy = proxy
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button("Go to 990") {
                        scrollProxy?.scrollTo(990, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #if os(macOS)
        .frame(minWidth: 500, minHeight: 300)
        #endif
    }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image: After tapping on Go to 990, doesn't scroll to 990 top]

Comment: you could try adding `.id(index)` to the `VStack`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried embedding the list inside the VStack and added id to the cell, but doesn't work. Could you try it

Comment: your code seems to work well for me, even without the `.id(index)`, on macos 13 Ventura, using xcode 14.1-beta, target macCatalyst and ios-16.
Tested on real devices, not Previews. It may be different on older systems. My previous comment is to add `.id(index)` to the VStack you have.

Comment: I am using Xcode 14.1 beta 2 on macOS 13.0 Beta (22A5352e) and doesn't work. Which Xcode beta (1 or 2) and which macOS 13 Beta are you using? I also tried adding `index` to the VStack

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Please test using iPhone 14 Pro simulator, also you could try running the app on macOS 13 Ventura.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine The anchor (top) is not respected, it just scrolls, but doesn't scroll to top though it can. Second time it works as expected

Comment: I'm on macos 13.0 Beta (22A5352e), using xcode 14.1-beta2. Yeah, on the simulator 14 pro, 
the first time, it scrolls to 990 in the middle of the screen. The second time, it is at the top.

Comment: Exactly, that is the same issue I am facing as well. I would expect it to scroll to top the first time (because that is what is mentioned in the code and it is possible).

Comment: Same behaviour on mac Catalyst, but on macos only, it scrolls, but well short of 990 the first time, 
but to 990 on top the second time. Could be a bug.

Comment: Is this a bug? Is there a workaround to fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248243/discussion-between-user1046037-and-workingdog-support-ukraine).

Comment: seeing similar behaviour on ios16...scrollView is not moving to top

Comment: I have filed a feedback, this seems like a bug with the framework. Hopefully it gets fixed